# Changing JPanel while hitting JButton in Swing using IntelIJ IDEA GUI Designer

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, gui-designer

I am working with IntelIJ and what I am trying to do is:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MOgI.png]

While hitting the Panel1Button the right JPanel should switch on the Panel1 and analogical with the Panel2Button but what happens is some small square appears.

Code:

```
GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
Panel1 p1;
Panel2 p2;
private JButton panel1Button;
private JButton panel2Button;
private JPanel DynamicPanel;
private JPanel mainPanel;

public Frame1(){
    p1 = new Panel1();
    p2 = new Panel2();

    DynamicPanel.setLayout(layout);
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    DynamicPanel.add(p1);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    DynamicPanel.add(p2);
    p1.setVisible(false);
    p2.setVisible(false);

    panel1Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Button1");
            p1.setVisible(true);
            p2.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
    panel2Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Button2");
            p1.setVisible(false);
            p2.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

I'm also want to separate the p1 and p2 panels in different classes. 
Panel1 and Panel2 looks like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jneQP.png]

Answer (score 0):

> While hitting the Panel1Button the right JPanel should switch on the Panel1 and analogical with the Panel2Button

Then the panel on the right should be using a `CardLayout`. Then you can just swap panels when you click on the button.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and working examples.